Heart Rate Variability and Morbidity/Mortality
My Apple watch measures my Heart Rate Variability every 4 hours automatically and each time reports the HRV in milliseconds. They define HRV as 1 standard deviation of the all the R-R intervals during each observation period (usually 60 seconds).
Is there good scientific evidence that HVR is a prognostic factor of cardiac health? What is the relationship between HVR and overall and cardiac-related morbidity and mortality?
Both WebMD and Wikipedia claim so but don’t indicate the strength of the correlation.

Hi and welcome. Are there two definitions for HRV that you're comparing? (You've given the Apple definition.) Are you asking if your cardiologist is correct? (<- We won't answer this.) We can't answer questions asking for medical advice; removing personal info and reformulating the question would be helpful in getting you an answer.

Adding to anongoodnurse's comment: are you measuring using the same device? It seems likely based on the numbers you give that these are two entirely different measurements. "Variability" is more of a general concept than it is a specific measurement. That doesn't mean any different measurements encompassed by that term are right or wrong, they're...different.

I don't see that there's anything here that we can answer that your cardiologist (a specialist in the field) can't. A bad cardiac condition can be caused by many things. The WebMD page has this to say, which might clear up your confusion: In healthy adults, average heart rate variability is 42 milliseconds. The range is between19 and 75 milliseconds. So your husband has normal and you not so much. Be aware that watch measures of this are quite variable and not very accurate as they can depend on things like how you wear your watch and how much hair you have on your arm.

@bob1, actually the Apple derived HRV is (for me) very accurate as it actually mirrors both Kardia ECG and hospital ECG results taken at the same time. I think what I'm trying to find out is: is one measure of HRV taken completely at rest (as in Apple Watch)  OR is the "higher is better" comparing BPMs between relaxed and stressed states.

@bob1, the same WebMD article goes on to say: "In general, it's better to have a high heart rate variability because it means that your body is adapting to change and stress more efficiently. Athletes and fit people tend to have a high heart rate variability." -- I can assure you that I am no athlete or "fit" with an HRV of >130 ms

@BobE Yes, sounds right - so a longer time variability is worse, shorter is better (to a point presumably), so your initial interpretation was incorrect; simple fix.

@bob1, BobE: Please know that HRV is very variable (no pun intended) from person to person, and it's a mistake to pronounce anyone compromised based on HRV alone.

@bob1- Please, please, don't use WebMD for anything meaningful in medicine. It's about as reliable as Wikipedia is in that area, which is poor (imo). So your comment is basically about as helpful as the one-line cardiologist's (reported) summation.

This is an interesting question including your comments (minus the personal info) that's deserving of a good (and reliably supported) answer. I'd add that I suspect either the cardiologist gave a more complete answer or that they are basing it on HRV plus other info they have about your medical history/test results.

As stated in the first comment, removing personal info and reformulating the question would be helpful in getting you an answer. I doubt you'll get an answer without doing so.

As @anongoodnurse pointed out, the personal info in your question makes people reluctant to answer, and it also makes it borderline off topic. You could easily attract 3 close votes, so I recommend editing those details out, which should be quite easy.

Hi and welcome, I‘ve taken the liberty to edit and streamline your question a bit more, please feel free to roll-back the edits if you do not agree :). I don’t think there are conflicting definitions/interpretations of HVR and in general (in theory) a high HVR is indicative of an „adaptive heart“ that can still respond to different stress factors and so in theory should indicate better cardiac health. It is just one indicator of cardiac health of many, however. From what I understood, you want to know how good of an indicator for cardiac health HRV is?

@Narusan The section "Analysis" on the Wikipedia page mentions several approaches for calculating HRV; these will each give different numbers.

@Narusan There's the problem that I have with offering the question - and avoiding any personal info - At 2:30 this morning my HRV was 140, at 3:30 this morning my HRV was 25 (by the same measurement system). And BTW, I see this happening over and over. So, how is it possible that cardiac health shifts between better and worse in the course of an hour. (I use 2:30 and 3:30 to illustrate)

@BobE "how is it possible that cardiac health shifts between better and worse in the course of an hour" - It doesn't. You mentioned that in some cases they are correlated. Correlation does not mean they are equal or change at the same rate. The average temperature around the surface of Earth is increasing over time. That does not mean it's warm, everywhere, today. The most likely explanation in your case is that you have a non-medical device, non-validated toy on your wrist that is not approved to diagnose any medical condition. If you have questions about your own health ask your doctor.

@BobE - I was going to answer this interesting question, but as you persist in making it personal, I don't feel that I can, because my answer will be interpreted as an opinion on your personal information. If you do a Google Scholar search of the subject, you will see a lot of papers, most more informative than WebMD. I have to agree with the above comment.

I still think the current question is answerable, and I actually have not found a prospective analysis of the relationship between HVR and morbidity/mortality in middle-aged, healthy patients. That HVR is not validated outside of those critically-ill after myocardial infarction (at least that is the only good paper I found so far) is an interesting and objective answer. Of course, in the end @BryanKrause is right with the non-medical, invalidated toy. Don’t have enough time to go through most of the literature atm so will write an answer later. But I think this is a non-personal way to answer

There might be. I have more time than you do, and have done some reading, too. Just don't like the fact that OP keeps bringing it around to themselves... :( To me, it would end up taken as medical advice.

I have to agree that you've made it crystal clear this question is entirely about your own personal health and you won't allow it to be made into the more interesting generic question that @Narusan went to the trouble of editing for you. Therefore, closed.

@anongoodnurse - well I'm not thrilled that I have to use my personal data AS AN EXAMPLE, but I don't know any other way to present the question. I appreciate Narusan' attempt to sanitize my original question, but I'm afraid that he broadened it way beyond my original intended scope.

As to Bryan contention that the apple watch is a invalidated toy, cardiologists generally accept ECGs generated by Apple Series IX and Kardia; simply because the device is in the hands of a consumer does not invalidate their use.

Maybe the better way to ask the question would be this: What (if any) is the significance of an Heart Rate Variation that fluctuates wildly over a short period of time for no apparent reason. By wildly I mean by a factor of 100.

@BobE - The Apple watch is a valuable tool. Narusan broadened it so that it could be answered, and you would have learned that HVR is more than some fixed-value  number that you might be quite puzzled about. I'm sorry this won't get an answer.

@BobE Cardiologists do not "generally accept ECGs generated by Apple Series IX and Kardia". They are willing to investigate a patient's concerns about their health, whatever generates those concerns. That's their job.

@BryanKrause - You're right. (BobE, the watch is valuable, but not much for an EKG.) They are, however, superb for other things; my youngish cardiologist recommended that I get one, lol. Lots of cardiologists wear them, but which came first, the money/status to buy one, or its utility? I think it's safe to guess that the former came first...

@anongoodnurse, We could debate the utility of Apple watches, the one thing I'm sure of however is that my wife's electrophysiologist askes her to send an Apple EKG weekly. and our recent experience while in hospital was that the Apple EKG tracing and the Kardia EKG tracing matched the hospital's  in-room cardiac monitor.

In the UK the NHS tends towards (or at least tended towards) using professional equipment designed for the purpose, electrodes on the thorax etc. or even a temporary implant, and wearing them for extended periods to record variability over days, weeks or even many months. What jurisdiction are you based in out of curiosity?

@BobE - The key word here being electrophysiologist and the single most clinically useful aspect of an Apple watch. You are misunderstanding something when ascribing its usefulness to its EKG function. Again, had you any patience, you'd have learned why. Your stubborn insistence has cost you some useful knowledge.

@JiminyCricket. - In the US at least, today's diagnostic outpatient heart monitors are usually single lead. Which puts the Apple watch in pretty much the same category.

The Kardia tracings (6 lead) match the Apple's PPG based tracings., Apple IX uses the same technology and allegedly the same microchip , as the hospital/doctor's office pulse ox. (The manufacturer of hospital based equipment is suing Apple for patent infringement and theft).

I have now gotten an answer to my original question- unfortunately, no thanks to this forum. The answer has nothing to do with a medical opinion or advice, and has application to approximately 6 million Americans.  It is clearly is in the realm of medical science .

@JiminyCricket  Just to button this up, I've been referring to the EKG traces, NOT to the interpretation of the trace by Apple or Kardia.
